# laravel PHPUnit test configuration been overriden by .env

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.5

I'm having this weird problem that doesn't always happen and sometimes `php artisan config:cache` fixes it.

Sometimes when I run phpunit test, it loads the local environment configuration and messes up the database. Changing values in `phpunit.xml` doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

Any idea why this happening and how to fix this?

I've tried overriding the `createsApplication` method and manually set the environment variables, clearing cache, caching config, PHPStorm test suit with custom configuration.

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
</php>
```

Comment: Please attach your `phpunit.xml` file.

Comment: Did you try using an env for testing? Placing a .env.testing with the necessary test-config should override any other .env or configuration while testing.

Comment: No, haven't done that. Shouldn't `phpunit.xml` be enough?

Comment: By the way, I've deleted the cached config file in bootstrap folder and everything's fine now.